# What do Ideals tell you?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I'm revising definitions of algebra for my exam and I'm wondering what an Ideal actually is?

I believe the definition is:

$I$ is an ideal of $R$ if $xr,rx\in I$ where $r\in R$ and $x\in I$

However, after looking about the web, I'm finding that unity has a lot to do with it. I'm struggling to find out how though. I know a unit is an element which can be multiplied by another element in the set (is set the right word?) to get 1.

Essentially I'm asking what it means for a ring to have unity? and what doe an Ideal mean/tell you

I'm just looking for some clarification on this, so any explanation would help, and an example would be great. We were asked to find all Ideals in $Z_6$ today and I didn't understand at the time, so this as an example explained would help me a lot.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Before getting to ideals you should really get comfortable with the very basics like units or zero divisors. Because you messed them up in your post.

Comment: okay, thanks I will

Comment: In a broad and fuzzy sense, ideal : ring :: normal subgroup : group .

Comment: It would be good to ask about what the identity implies in a separate post. These two questions are really very different. Actually, there is probably already an answer dealing with that too, so on second thought, search for it first.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever we study a new algebraic object like a group or a ring, one of the most useful things to study is the maps between those objects. In group theory, we are interested in homomorphisms between groups. In ring theory, we are interested in homomorphisms between rings. Knowing about the possible homomorphisms from a ring $R$ into other rings can give you a large amount of information about the ring you started with, in exactly the same way that, for example, knowing how a group $G$ acts on different sets (i.e. homomorphisms $G\to S_n$) tells you a lot about $G$. This makes homomorphisms a useful thing to study.

Given a homomorphism of rings
$$\theta: R \to S$$
we have the **kernel** of this homomorphism
$$\ker\theta = \{r\in R : \theta(r ) = 0\}$$
You can think of the kernel as a measure of how much information about the ring $R$ this homomorphism captures. If $\ker\theta$ is very small, the homomorphism $\theta$ captures a lot of information. If $\ker\theta = \{0\}$, then $\theta$ is injective - i.e. it is an isomorphism onto its image. In this case $\theta$ loses no information. On the other extreme, if $\ker\theta = R$, then the image of $\theta$ is trivial - i.e. $\theta$ loses all information about the original ring $R$ (apart from the fact that it is a ring).

**So what about ideals?**

In group theory, we are interested in normal subgroups because they correspond exactly to kernels of group homomorphisms. In ring theory, ideals are the analogue of normal subgroups - ideals correspond exactly to kernels of homomorphisms.

Notice that $\ker\theta$ is always an ideal of $R$. It is certainly a subgroup of $R$ (since $\theta$ is a homomorphism of additive groups), and if $x\in\ker \theta$ and $r\in R$, then $$\theta(rx) = \theta(r )\theta(x) = \theta(r )\cdot 0 = 0$$
so $rx\in \ker\theta$. And every ideal is a kernel of a homomorphism: if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then the homomorphism
$$\theta: R\to R/I\\r\mapsto r+ I$$
has $\ker\theta = I$.

Just like in group theory, we have isomorphism theorems connecting quotient groups and images of homomorphisms - $$R/\ker\theta \cong \mathrm{Im}(\theta)$$

But unlike in group theory, a ring has additional structure that leads us to talking about things like units, zero divisors, prime and maximal ideals.

---

**Example:** $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$

First note that if $R$ is any ring and $u\in R$ is a unit (i.e. $\exists v\in R$ such that $uv = 1$), then any ideal $I$ containing $u$ will be the entire ring $R$. This is because if $u\in I$, then $1= uv \in I$, and hence for any $r\in R$, $r = ruv \in R$. So $R\subset I$.

Hence, in our case, we only need to consider ideals containing elements of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ which are not units - i.e. $2,3,4\pmod 6$.

Note also that if $I$ is an ideal, then $2 \in I \iff 4 \in I$, since $4 \equiv -2 \pmod 6$, and $2 \in I \iff -2\in I$. Hence we only need to consider ideals containing $2,3\pmod 6$.

Let $I$ be an ideal containing *both* $2,3\pmod 6$. Then $I$ contains $3-2 = 1$, so by the same argument as above, $I=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$.

This shows us that the only ideals of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ are $\{0\}$, $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ where $(x)$ means the ideal generated by $x$ - i.e.
$$(x) = \{y \in R: y = rx \text{ for some }r\in R\}$$

Answer (score 1):

For Emmy Noether an ideal was basically a modulus, as in solving an equation modulo 5.  She gets this from Dedekind but makes it more far-reaching.

For her arithmetic modulo 5 was properly done as algebra in the ring  $\mathbb{Z}/(5)$ where $(5)$ is the ideal generated by $5\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Of course she knew many other examples, such as that the ring of regular functions on an algebraic variety is a ring of polynomials modulo some ideal -- namely the ideal generated by the polynomials that define the variety.

The intuition there is that if you define the circle by equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$ then a regular function on the circle is given by any polynomial in $x,y$, but two polynomials determine the same regular function on the circle iff they are equal modulo $x^2+y^2-1$ so they restrict to the same function on the points of the circle.

Noether was keenly aware that ideals in a ring $R$ and quotients of the ring amount to the same thing.  She compared this to the way quotients of a group $G$ amount to the same thing as *normal* subgroups of $G$, not all subgroups.  She captured this in her family of *homomorphism and isomorphism* theorems.